# Create Nested Resource at same time as Parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles, nested-resources

I have three models Session, Attendee, Role. Attendee is nested within Session and Role is a separate model.

I want to be able to Create a new Session and when the session is created a attendee is created for that session that has the Role "Owner".

I am drawing a blank on two things:

1) How to add a Attendee to the Session upon creating

2) How to find the ID for the role "Owner" and add it as a parameter for the Attendee.

Look forward to hearing from y'all!

:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of options.

Add it to `after_create` or `before_create` callback on Session.

```
class Session
   after_create :create_attendee

   def create_attendee
      Attendee.create(session: this)
   end
end

class Session
   before_create :build_attendee

   def build_attendee
      this.attendees << Attendee.new(...)
   end
end
```

Create it explicitly while creating your session object

```
session = Session.new(..)
session.attendees << Attendee.new(..)
session.save
```